# How can I compare letters and their corresponding (alphabetically) numbers in Perl?

Tags: perl, comparison, operator-overloading, versioning

I should compare some application's versions using Perl. And the problem is, that the last part of every version can be set by numbers as well as by alphabetically corresponding letters, that is:

```
12.3a == 12.31
12.3b == 12.32
12.3c <> 12.34
```

I saw the [version module](http://search.cpan.org/~jpeacock/version-0.97/lib/version.pod) but it seems to deal only with numbers and underlines.
Maybe I should use [overload](http://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html)?
What is the best and most elegant solution?

Comment: Erm... how about just 'normalizing' (replacing the ending letters with numbers) the string you are to compare first? Is it always the single letter, and should it always be replaced directly - i.e., 'a' to 1, 'b' to 2 etc.?

Comment: Will you get letters higher than "i"?

Comment: @raina77ow: It is not always the single letter, but it should be replaced directly. Besides, there could a lot of letters, so the replacement process itself would be rather complex.

Comment: @ikegami: Letters higher than "i" are probable, but not likely. So, the solution for only letters lower than "i" would also be great.

Comment: Where I was going with this: Is `12.3j` equivalent to anything?

Comment: @ikegami: I see now - than yes, there couldn't be a letter higher than "i". Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a weird spec. Normalisation is probably the way to go.

```
use version qw( qv );

sub normalise_version {
    my ($v) = @_;
    $v =~ s/([a-i])/ ord($1)-ord('a')+1 /eg;
    return qv("v$v");
}

normalise_version($v1) <=> normalise_version($v2)
```

With the above 12.3 is considered smaller than 12.31. Let me know if that's wrong.

Comment: Actually since we are dealing with version 12.3a is probably an alpha version and should be smaller than 12.3

Comment: @Matteo, that directly contradicts what the OP asked.

Comment: Yes, version 12.3a is really smaller than 12.3, but in my situation version 12.3a is equal to 12.31.

Comment: @ikegami: Thank you, it works for now. But couldn't you extend your answer a bit and explain what `return qv("v$v");` would change?

Comment: @evgeny9, Which is larger, 12.3 or 12.31? By using a version object, 12.31 is considered larger.

Comment: @ikegami: Sorry, didn't refresh and see the update. Yes, you're right, 12.3 is considered smaller than 12.31. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Sort::Versions](http://search.cpan.org/~edavis/Sort-Versions-1.5/Versions.pm). From the module description:

> Sort::Versions allows easy sorting of mixed non-numeric and numeric strings, like the 'version numbers' that many shared library systems and revision control packages use. This is quite useful if you are trying to deal with shared libraries. It can also be applied to applications that intersperse variable-width numeric fields within text. Other applications can undoubtedly be found.

Comment: Thank you, this module seems to do the exact thing. But again, "not `lib`" modules, unfortunately, are undesirable for me as the resulting script should be portable between different PCs (and even several Perl versions) without additional PPM installations.

Comment: It is a single module which you can bundle with your code and since the code is less than 20 lines you could even embed it.

Comment: Thank you, I never bundled or embedded modules, so I didn't even think of this option. I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen David Wheeler's [SemVer](https://metacpan.org/module/SemVer)?

Comment: Thank you, no, I have not. But I don't see an option to replace letters with numbers in its description, besides it is highly preferable for me to use only standard modules.

Comment: I don't think it provides any such thing, but it overloads comparison so you can do a: `SemVer->new("12.3a") < SemVer->new("12.3c")` comparison. If you really just want numeric conversion instead and/or no help from CPAN, then go with @ikegami's answer. That's probably the best you'll get.

Comment: I doubt `SemVer->new("12.3a") == SemVer->new("12.31")` is true.

Comment: I doubt it too, but it seems like a pretty lame spec if that's what one really wants. I can't imagine that yielding any useful comparison of version numbers in the real world. Of course, in the real world, so many version numbers are arbitrary and non-semantic, that comparing them globally is an effort in futility. You always need an exception to every rule.

Comment: This is why Perl modules are required to use version numbers that can be converted to decimal form and nothing else. The number `v5.6.1` translates to `5.006001` but what's `v5.6.1a`? Rather than guessing, it's just not allowed. This is a good policy for making CPAN installation tools work as well as they do in resolving dependency requirements.

Comment: @zostay: I can understand your confusion. But I didn't advertise any specs - it was just a task to compare a set of numbers (strings). And ikegami's solution was just what I needed: now I am able to compare such sets without changing any specs which i could not. Thanks!